# Typescript Generic to map an array of const objects to a list of types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have some JSON data that I've strongly typed with an `as const` assertion.

```js
const myList = [
  { type: 'uint256'},
  { type: 'address'}
] as const;
```

Now I want to convert this to the following tuple type:

```js
[number, string]
```

Basically, if the type is "address" it should resolve to `string`.

If the type is a "uint256", it should resolve to `number`.

I intend to use this type to create arrays of data that conform to this schema, eg:

```js
const foo: ConvertToTuple<typeof myList> = [1, 'asdf'];
```

I'm struggling to write a generic that can do this. Here's where I'm at so far:

```js
type ConvertToTuple<
  DataObjects extends readonly { type: "address" | "uint256" }[]
> = DataObjects extends readonly [infer CurrentObject, ...infer RestObjects]
  ? CurrentObject["type"] extends "address"
    ? [string, ...ConvertToTuple<RestObjects>]
    : CurrentObject["type"] extends "uint256"
    ? [number, ...ConvertToTuple<RestObject>]
    : never
  : [];
```

I don't think I'm using `infer` correctly here. Typescript is throwing a couple of errors:

```
Type '"type"' cannot be used to index type 'CurrentObject'
```

and

```
Type 'RestObjects' does not satisfy the constraint 'readonly { type: "address" | "uint256"; }[]'.
  Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly { type: "address" | "uint256"; }[]'.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ type: "address" | "uint256"; }'.
```

Any help untangling this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript added [`extends` constraints on `infer` type variables](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables) in version 4.7, so you can simplify the recursive mapped type utility like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=13&ssc=11&pln=4&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgZ2AFXNAvFARAQwCZ4BOECCWUAPtgK5wB2wATAKwBsWA3AFCiSyLAAogBsIAWwgMomAN5ReEAFz8kqPgF9uPNFGSEcdBADMA9oTEAeZNTBQIAD2CS8CKMXwm6wkCqGiJDADaALoAfNJcULo2do7Oru54nt5QgZFRUPRGEIRQABKxTnQuviLiksAANOlRAHT1WTlQAEqF8W4QHl4+8EhlAcAh6cE1UAD8qaNReYFYCljBbcWuuATEpOQTSIT0AOZQynTUYgBGOdUZGfW1egbGZpbNoaMjl8rWYFoAxp5IUGIgXrAaSTKJyBTKLC0BgsdhQdQXKDgtCQ-BEEhkeHVRY4Vw-QzAhA4YCIIxwEgdLopIH9CohLQKKAAMRMJhBt0MpnMFgUJiM-0BAlC3AyAHpRQA9MZcLj4v6mEzKFlszCBACMlWwuLwRgWHCg4qgJgA1lwgA)

```ts
type ListType = "address" | "uint256";
type ListElement = { type: ListType };

type Transform<Tup extends readonly ListElement[]> =
  Tup extends readonly [
    infer H extends ListElement,
    ...infer R extends readonly ListElement[]
  ]
    ? [
      H["type"] extends "address" ? string : number,
      ...Transform<R>
    ]
    : Tup;

const myList = [
  { type: "uint256" },
  { type: "address" },
] as const satisfies readonly ListElement[];

type Foo = Transform<typeof myList>;
   //^? type Foo = [number, string]

const foo: Foo = [1, "asdf"]; // ok
```

---

If your enumeration of possible string literal types ends up growing, you can also use a type mapping of string literals to their corresponding types like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgZ2AFXNAvFARAQwCZ4BOECCWUAPtgK5wB2wATAKwBsWA3AFCiSyLAAogBsIAWwgMomAN5ReEAFz8kqPgF9uPNFGSEcdBADMA9oTFqIAWRxhpUGVyhR8REgmVJC9AObdntAwsrMp01GIARhCE3Jpc2nx6BsZmYgA8yNR2EAAewJJ4CFDE+CZ0wiAqQqISDADaALoAfNJOullQufl0hcUQpeWVdW3O9EbRUAASnXkFRfBIIuKSwAA0I1AAdNtjEwBKM929JXhlFVVLtcCNbQ0bAPxQdUmGpuaWNmB1k3VYClgNBqrLbbF4pcxpPZNO7OZzKTJgLQAYzKSCgYhAC2A9mGzjkCmUWECTDY5HU6zx8jQhNcxFIZPWDRcRRRhmxCBwwEQRjgJD6A3OWMuK0aWgUUAAYiYTPYwW90goTEZ0ZiBE1-M4APSagB693irLRphMyilMswdQAjMDcAg8EYARwoNqoCYANZcIA)

```ts
type TransformTypeMap = {
  address: string;
  uint256: number;
};

type Transform<Tup extends readonly ListElement[]> =
  Tup extends readonly [
    infer H extends ListElement,
    ...infer R extends readonly ListElement[]
  ]
    ? [TransformTypeMap[H["type"]], ...Transform<R>]
    : Tup;
```